# Can I do a Deep Rock Galactic promotion assignment on a different class than the one I am promoting?

Tags: deep-rock-galactic

If I start the Driller Promotion Assignment (for example) do I have to complete the missions on the Driller? Or can I use one of the other three classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can complete them on **any** of the four classes and still get credit.

It is actually better to use a different class because the class you are promoting has already hit their experience cap and so won't benefit from the experience points awarded at the end of each mission.